# Lua Error: '<eof>' expected

Tags: lua, eof, computercraft

There is an error that I can not get away from. When I run the script, the following error occurs every time:

```
bios:14: [string "Digger"]:35: '<eof>' expected

write("X:")
x = read()
write("Y:")
y = read()
write("Z:")
z = read()
for zi=0, z, 1 do
    for xi=0, x, 1 do
        for yi=0, y, 1 do
            turtle.dig()
            turtle.forward()
        end
        if xi < x then
            if xi % 2 then
                turtle.turnLeft()
                turtle.dig()
                turtle.forward()
                turtle.turnLeft()
            else
                turtle.turnRight()
                turtle.dig()
                turtle.forward()
                turtle.turnRight()
            end
        end
    end
    if y % 2 == 1 then
        turtle.turnRight()
        for back=0, y, 1 do
            turtle.forward()
        end
        turtle.turnRight()
    end 
end
```

Although I have already found out in the internet that there must be an end to much, but I find no mistake. Can you tell me what's wrong?

Comment: In which environment are you running the script?

Comment: Your code is syntactically correct.  BTW, `if xi % 2` will be always interpreted as `if true` (in Lua, zero is true).

Comment: In Minecraft: Computercraft ^^
How can I differentiate between odd and even in Lua?

Comment: `if xi % 2 == 1`

Comment: do you have more code than that? I can't find any error here

Comment: @TimoSpielberger Are you still active here?